# Take File and Split Into Two LinkedLists to Determine if Second List has numbers that are in first list

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I'm supposed to take a file that has integers in individual lines and scan that into a list. Then I'm to break this list into two linked lists. And finally I need to say if a number in the second list is in the first one.

I understand (at least I think I do) the second part of this. And I feel like I understand how to do the entire problem because I can't find a flaw in my logic but the command doesn't seem to work.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FindKeys {

private static LinkedList<Integer> foo;
private static LinkedList<Integer> list1;
private static LinkedList<Integer> list2;
private static TreeMap<Integer, Boolean> list3;
private static int firstValue;
private static int numberA;
private static int numberB;

public FindKeys() {
}

public void main(String [] args) {
    foo = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    read(foo);
    listA(foo);
    listB(foo);
    discover(list1);
    print(list3);
}

private void read(LinkedList<Integer> foo){
    Scanner scan;
    int number;
    try{
        scan = new Scanner( new FileReader("Stuff.txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException f){
        System.err.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: " + f.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    while(scan.hasNextInt()){
        number = scan.nextInt();
        foo.add(number);
    }
}

private void listA(LinkedList<Integer> foo){



    firstValue = foo.getFirst();

    for( int i = 1; i<firstValue; i++){
        System.out.println(foo.get(i));

        int temp = foo.get(i);
  //This is where the issue is.

        list1.set(i,temp);
    }
}

private void listB(LinkedList<Integer> foo){



    firstValue = foo.getFirst();

    for( int i = firstValue; i<foo.size(); i++){
        numberB = foo.get(i);
        list2.add(numberB);
    }
}

private void discover(LinkedList<Integer> list1){
    for(int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++){           
        if(list2.contains(list1.get(i))){
            boolean a = true;
            list3.put(list1.get(i),a);
            return;

        }
        boolean b = false;
        list3.put(list1.get(i),b);
    }
}

private void print(TreeMap<Integer, Boolean> list3){
    for(int numberA : list1){
        System.out.printf("%3i   %b" , numberA, list3);
    }
}
}
```

The issues comes when I am trying to add the number from the first list into the second one. And the problem seems to be that the LinkedList list1 has a size of 0. I thought that this was a simple misunderstanding on my part, that I didn't understand how to change the size of a list or how to add one more each time that I put on a new element but I can't find this in the first 20 pages of Google nor on this site. Having said that, I'm going to also assume that someone on here has this magical connection to the search gods and can possibly point me in the right direction, or maybe just tell me why that I can't add to the list. It just tells me that there is an issue because:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at FindKeys.listA(FindKeys.java:58)
at FindKeys.main(FindKeys.java:21)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at FindKeys.listA(FindKeys.java:58)
at FindKeys.main(FindKeys.java:21)
```

and quite frankly I don't know what that means and when I looked it up I got more confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the data structures

```
private static LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
private static LinkedList<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
private static TreeMap<Integer, Boolean> list3 = new TreeMap<Integer, Boolean>();
```

and `main` method

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    FindKeys fk = new FindKeys();
    foo = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    fk.read(foo);
    fk.listA(foo);
    fk.listB(foo);
    fk.discover(list1);
    fk.print(list3);
}
```